# Sum of two values in the range of $\sigma_1(n)$

Tags: number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

Q: Is it true that for $n>3$, there exists $u$ and $v$ in $\mathbb N$ such that
$$n=\sigma_1(u)+\sigma_1(v),$$
where $\sigma_1(k)$ is the sum of the positive integer divisors of $k$, $k\in \mathbb N$? I assume this is true and may seem to be connected with Goldbach conjecture but clearly should be a lot easier. For instance, if $n\ge 8$ is even, then assuming that Goldbach conjecture is true,
$$n-2=p+q\implies\ n=p+1+q+1=\sigma(p)+\sigma(q)$$
for some primes $p$ and $q$. So, the answer to Q would be Yes if we assume Goldbach and $n$ even. There seems to be no simple way to do something similar for $n$ odd.

The numbers in the range of $\sigma_1(n)$ less than 100 are
$$A=\{ 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 20, 24, 28, 30, 31, 32, 36, 
38, 39, 40, 42, 44, 48, 54, 56, 57, 60, 62, 63, 68, 72, 74, 78, 80, 
84, 90, 91, 93, 96, 98\}.$$

The list of $a+b$ with $a,b\in A$, and then sorted is 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10,
11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15,
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18,
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20,...
20, 20

which makes the conjecture (Q true) very plausible. I wonder if this is already known.   This is a question asked by Sourav Mandal on Research Gate.

As one can read below, it is likely that if $n\ge 7$, one can find $u$ a prime.

Comment: Have you tried to check the conjecture for a non-trivial range?  Have you shown that this follows from any of the more standard conjectures?

Comment: Obviously there are lots of small values for $\sigma_1$, but the asymptotic density of such values is $0$, so looking at small values might not be indicative.

Comment: Since $\sigma(p)=p+1$ (for $p$ prime) one can show that Goldbach conjecture being true implies this one true for $n$ even. I am not  sure what the non-trivial range would be.

Comment: I understand that one may have surprises for big $n$.

Comment: I suggest editing to include the Goldbach observation (+1).  It's something, at least.  As you are aware, proving statements like this is often beyond current techniques.  Checking the first billion or so numbers is usually a good idea.  The more, the better.  Though maybe the Goldbach observation already gives us a huge number of cases?

Comment: I did added that!

Comment: Excellent!  Though, like I mentioned, if all the data for Goldbach backs this as well, then the possible counterexamples are way, way beyond any undirected search.  So, numerical evidence won't help.

Comment: This sounds like a true conjecture, especially for even $n$. The even values of $\sigma_1(n)$ have positive density, which to me makes it extremely likely that the sums of two such include all (sufficiently large) even integers. But I couldn't track down any statements to this effect (even though it seems likely that some researcher has looked at this question).

Comment: Is $2\sigma(u)$ (identical numbers $u$ and $v$) allowed as well ?

Comment: @Peter I think that is fine. One may perhaps ask that $u\not=v$, but I have a feeling this makes no difference for $n$ big enough.

Comment: @EugenIonascu  For every odd $n$ with $7\le n\le 10^8$ , there is such a representation with $u$ prime.

Comment: Extended to $10^9$

Comment: @Peter Very good!  And I guess we can upgrade the conjecture. Is there a way to link your search results or how you did the search ?